# What can we do with the Dump contexts?

Tags: undocumented, contexts, searching

So we know from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/what-is-the-purpose-of-dump-contexts) what the `*Dump` contexts signify and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71301/38205) Rojo found a very useful goody that involves them:

```
In[320]:= StyleManager`OpenStyleManager // OwnValues

Out[320]= {HoldPattern[StyleManager`OpenStyleManager] :> 
  System`Dump`AutoLoad[Hold[StyleManager`OpenStyleManager], 
    Hold[StyleManager`OpenStyleManager], 
    "NotebookTools`Stylesheets`"] /; System`Dump`TestLoad}
```

Note that this adds another auto-loading mechanism to the ones [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114956/what-are-package-context-symbols-for). Although a more restricted one.

What is interesting about this though is the context it loads: `` NotebookTools`StylesheetsDump` `` which contains a whole slew of fun symbols. Similarly there is a `` NotebookTools`ControlsDump` `` context we can play with.

We can figure out which Dumps can be loaded via this mechanism:

```
Cases[
   ToExpression[Names["*`*"], StandardForm, 
    OwnValues], {_ :> 
      Verbatim[Condition][System`Dump`AutoLoad[__, s_], ___]} :> s
   ] // DeleteDuplicates // Sort
(* The output is 1016 contexts long *)
```

But that's an overwhelming amount of stuff to try to trawl through to pull out gems like Rojo's.

All of this is build up to wondering if anyone else has a good way to find gems in these Dump contexts. I'm sure there's useful functionality buried in there, but I just don't know how to find it (i.e. every day using Mathematica).